# NameError: name 'SOCKETS' is not defined

Tags: sockets, network-programming, python-3.7

I am doing a course on Python, and I am trying to understand how the app SOCKET works. Could you please help with an error "NameError: name 'SOCKETS' is not defined" for this simple code? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import socket

c = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
c.send(cmd) 
while True:
    data = c.recv(512) 
    if (len(data)) < 1:
        break 
    print(data.decode()) 
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`import socket`; imports socket module. `socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`; socket module is not callable. You might want to use the function `socket.socket()`. There is no such thing as `SOCKETS` used in your code. You shouldn't be getting that error.